# Make latest collection created as active

Tags: python, collections

I'm trying to make a script that makes the latest created Collection as active right away. Is there a way to accomplish it or we just need to rely on the collection's name to make it active?

Comment: does 'latestet collection' mean the collection you've just created in Python or does it mean something else?

Comment: Yes, the latest collection is the one that was just created in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this discussion](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/set-active-collection/2409/4) on DevTalk it seems that the following will work:

```
import bpy

collection = bpy.data.collections.new("MyTestCollection")

bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)

bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[-1]
```

This is [because](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/set-active-collection/2409/2)

> It’s set per view layer as bpy.context.view_layer.collections.active. However the tricky thing is that this is a per view layer LayerCollection, rather than a Collection datablock.

> You can traverse the tree of LayerCollection in view_layer.collections and find the one that matches a specific Collection, and then set that. But we really need a simpler API for this.

You will have to adapt this code to your situation with respect to view layers, and which context you want.  Particularly if you use this in an operator's methods, you have to remove `bpy.` from `bpy.context...` because you want to use the context argument to the method.

Answer (score 3):

The active collection can be set per ViewLayer: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html#bpy.types.ViewLayer.active_layer_collection

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# create your collection 
coll = bpy.data.collections.new('MyCollection')
C.scene.collection.children.link(coll)

# make it active
layer_collection = C.view_layer.layer_collection.children[coll.name]
C.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layer_collection

print (C.collection)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I accepted the first answer since came first, but it is great to know that there are many way to accomplish what I was looking for.
If it is possible to accept two answer I will accept yours as well.